# PHP: Outputing elements from array in a random order, before they create a specific word

Tags: php, arrays, random

I want to create an array in PHP with 4 elements in it (for example "A", "l", "e", "x") and output this letters in a random order, before they create a word "Alex", after that array should stop.
So it should output something like this:
*Axel, leAx, xAle, ... Alex!* 
I have found out how to output random elements from array, but it doesn't work with 4 elements for me, and I don't know how to create a loop with it.

```
<?php
$name = array("A","l","e","x");
$rand_keys = array_rand($name, 2);
echo $name[$rand_keys[0]];
echo $name[$rand_keys[1]];
?>
```

this currently outputs 2 random elements and I'm stuck here(
Please help

Comment: There are probably several answers to this question already on stack overflow.

Comment: Use $rand_keys = array_rand($name, 4); This will pick four random elements.  But if you want all the elements every time, then you can try shuffle().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shuffle` to rearrange the order of elements in an array (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php). As this changes the original array you should create a copy first. Then use `implode` to create a string from the array (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). The same way store all shuffled names and use implode to concatenate them to a single string separated by comma.

```
<?php
$name = array("A","l","e","x");
$name_shuffled = $name;
$list_of_names = array();
do{
    shuffle($name_shuffled);
    $list_of_names[] = implode($name_shuffled);
} while ($name !== $name_shuffled);
echo(implode(', ', $list_of_names));
echo('!');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle it, well..

```
<?php 
$name = array("A","l","e","x");   
$copy = $name; 
do{  
shuffle($copy);
print_r($copy);   
}while($name !== $copy);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

something this work for me but not for array,for array must change little this code for your job.
look my idea

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
  <body>
   <table align='center' style='width: 100%; height: 30;'>
<tr>
<?php
 ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', true );
include ('data/data.php');

/* Call data from weather database  */
$data = "$WeatherIcon";

/* seperate weather condition icons to number */
if(preg_match('(clear.png)', $data) === 1) { $datatest=0; } 
if(preg_match('(mostlycloudy.png)', $data) === 1) { $datatest=1;  } 
if(preg_match('(partlycloudy.png)', $data) === 1) { echo $datatest=2;  } 
if(preg_match('(rain.png)', $data) === 1) { echo $datatest=3;  } 
if(preg_match('(nt_mostlycloudy.png)', $data) === 1) { $datatest=4;  } 
if(preg_match('(nt_cloudy.png)', $data) === 1) {  $datatest=5;  } 

/* a:{ΔΕΝ Βρέχει =0 ,Βρέχει =1}*/
  if   ($datatest <= 0 && $Rain_Rate <= 0 && $Temp <= 0 && $Temp >= -1) echo "GOOD WEATHER WITH COLD AND SOME ICE"; 
elseif ($datatest <= 0 && $Rain_Rate <= 0 && $Temp >= 0 && $Temp < 5) echo "GOOD WEATHER WITH COLD";
elseif ($datatest <= 0 && $Rain_Rate <= 0 && $Temp >= 5 && $Temp < 10) echo "GOOD WEATHER WITH SOME COLD"; 
elseif ($datatest <= 0 && $Rain_Rate <= 0 && $Temp >= 10 && $Temp < 20) echo "GOOD WEATHER WITH NORMAL TEMP"; 
elseif ($datatest <= 1) echo "GOOD WEATHER WITH MOSTLY CLOUD AND COLD";  
elseif ($datatest <= 2) echo "GOOD WEATHER WITH PARTLY CLOUD AND COLD ";  
elseif ($datatest <= 3) echo "RAINY DAY";  
elseif ($datatest <= 4) echo "<td bgcolor='#99ff99' align='center' style='width: 800px; height: 30;'>NIGHT GOOD WEATHER WITH MOSTLY CLOUD AND COLD</td>";  
elseif ($datatest <= 5) echo "<td bgcolor='#99ff99' align='center' style='width: 800px; height: 30;'>NIGHT CLOUDY WEATHER WITH COLD</td>";  
?>
</tr> 
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```